# Wrap a function with a decorator with AST in Python

Tags: python, decorator, abstract-syntax-tree

If I transform a program into an AST graph, could I directly modify the AST such that a function that the program calls (but doesn't define) is wrapped by a decorator?

Comment: If the program you have in AST form does not define the function, then it wouldn't normally be the place where a decorator would be applied.  But it would certainly be possible to insert the equivalent of `func = decorator(func)` in the AST - you'd just need to find a place after the import of the function, but before any call to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with [refactor](https://github.com/isidentical/refactor):

```
import refactor
from refactor import context

class AddDecorator(refactor.Rule):
    
    context_providers = (context.Ancestry,)

    decorators = {
        'call_a': 'decorator_a'
    }

    def match(self, node):
        # check if this is a call to a function specified in decorators
        assert isinstance(node, ast.Call)
        assert isinstance(node.func, ast.Name)
        assert node.func.id in self.decorators
        
        decorator_id = self.decorators[node.func.id]
        
        # check whether it is already wrapped to a decorator or not
        parent = self.context['ancestry'].get_parent(node)
        if isinstance(parent, ast.Call) and isinstance(parent.func, ast.Name):
            assert parent.func.id != decorator_id

        decorator_call = ast.Call(
            ast.Name(decorator_id, ast.Load()),
            args=[node],
            keywords=[]
        )
        return refactor.ReplacementAction(node, decorator_call)

session = refactor.Session(rules=[AddDecorator])
print(session.run("""
from x import call_a, call_b, call_c, decorator_a

@decorator_a
def call_d():
    # already decorated
    print(decorator_a(call_a()))
    
    # simple call
    z = call_a()
    return 'something'

# complex call
q = call_c(
    call_d(),
    call_a(),
    call_b()
)

some_others
"""))
```

It will produce the following code which wraps all `call_a()`s with `decorator_a()` if they are not already wrapped;

```py
from x import call_a, call_b, call_c, decorator_a


@decorator_a
def call_d():
    # already decorated
    print(decorator_a(call_a()))
    
    # simple call
    z = decorator_a(call_a())
    return 'something'

# complex call
q = call_c(
    call_d(),
    decorator_a(call_a()),
    call_b()
)

some_others
```